# Visual Studio Code can't validate PHP, I added it to the path, but it's still alerting me

Tags: php, validation, visual-studio-code, executable-path

That's the alert it's showing.

[image]

As you can see, I already set the path (I also tried another .exe, from WAMP), but it is still alerting that PHP executable wasn't found.

[image]

I have no idea why, but it started to happen after I installed this extension:

[image]

Before that it was set the same way as now (executablePath: php.exe) and it was all right. After I installed the PHP IntelliSense, I've found no way to fix that.
Hope some of you already faced this, and can help me.
Thanks!